# How not to process files which were already processed before? (they will not be zipped or renamed)

Tags: linux, bash, file

I have read-only access to the folder containing lot of logs with names starting with SystemOut*:

*SystemOut_15.03.12_1215124.log*
*SystemOut_15.03.12_23624.log*
*SystemOut_15.03.02_845645.log*
*SystemOut_15.03.14_745665.log*
*SystemOut_15.03.16_456457.log*
*SystemOut_15.03.07_474574.log*

The logs are not zipped or renamed.

What I need to implement is to parse them in such a way that the logs  already processed will not be processed again. Also, the mandatory condition is not to process the log with the latest modification date&time.

I would potentially think I need to create a separate file on a location I have write access with the log names my script has already processed?

Grateful if you could provide some suggestions and how to implement them.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree keeping track of the logs you have already processed in a separate file is a good idea. It's not clear from your question how you will identify the current log, so I leave that in your court.

Try something like this:

```
mysavedfiles=/some/path/file.txt
curfile=$(ls -tr | tail -n 1)
for fn in logfiles/*.log
do
    if ! grep -q $fn $mysavedfiles && [ "$fn" != "$curfile" ]
    then
        ... process it ...
        echo $fn >>$mysavedfiles
    fi
done
```

You could also exclude the last file by changing to a `while read` loop fed by some processing:

```
ls -tr logfile/*.log | head -n -1 | while read fn
do
    ....
done
```

Comment: Thanks Peter! The log with the latest modification time will be the current one.